# Translating Joomla User Menu

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, language-translation

Hi I'm looking to translate the Frontend User Menu for Joomla containing the menu:

- **User Menu**
- Your Profile
- Submit an Article
- Submit a Weblink
- Site Administrator
- Template Settings
- Site Settings

It's primary the Title and the first 3 options that I need to translate.

I've been searching my file directory almost whole day now to find the associated files, but without any luck.

I'm using the Danish language pack, and even if I set it as the default language for both frontend and backend, the frontend User Menu it still shows in English. Which makes me guess it's not located in any of the language folders...

Comment: Such questions should be asked here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHat you are trying to translate is the actual **titles** of the **menu items**, plus the **title of the module** that renders this menu.

For these:

- Your Profile
- Submit an Article
- Submit a Weblink
- Site Administrator
- Template Settings Site Settings

You need to go in the **menu manager**, I guess this menu should be called "**User Menu**" and edit the menu-items titles to your desired titles.

For the "User Menu", you need to go to **Module Manager** and find the **Menu Module** that renders this menu, should be called "**User Menu**" and change its title as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has an automatic search for language strings and override creation at:

```
Extensions -> Language Manager -> Overrides -> New
```

If search doesn't get results please try word by word because sometimes components use combination of strings.

If you still can't find the strings then there may be a menu at `Menus -> Menu Manager` that you could translate or these strings have been set in the code without string variables (you have to check your component / module).

Good Luck!